# Should I allow communication on public networks?

Tags: network, windows, firewalls

I apologize if this is a newb question. Reading this prompt, it appears that I should check Private Networks and uncheck Public Networks. However, Windows defaults to the opposite being checked.

Am I misreading this? Why is the default to allow public networks, and disallow private networks? Is there ever a case where it is appropriate to allow public but not private?

[image: Windows Security Alert]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same feelings as you regarding the default selection being set to public.  After reading the other answers to this question I didn't really feel like they directly addressed your question around why Public is set to the default. So, I've done some testing and have found the following:

**The default selection is based on the state of your current network.** It is not based on what is considered best practice for firewall rules. If the network that you are on is set to Public, then the default checkbox is set to Public.

I think that most of us generally consider our home networks to be Private, however Windows cannot assume that is the case and so by default your network is set as Public. You can follow the steps below to set your trusted home network to Private. **After you have done this, you will notice that future security prompts will default to Private rather than Public.**

#### How to set your Trusted Home Network as a "Private" Network (windows 10):

1. Open up `Network & Internet Settings` (this should bring open the network "Status" section by default)[image: Status section within Network & Internet Settings]
2. Click on "Change connection properties". If you have more than one network adapter, you may be connected to more than one network.  Make sure you're selecting the correct one.
3. Select "Private" for the Network profile.[image: Setting Network profile to Private]

#### What the default selection looks like after setting your Network to "Private":

[image: Default selection is set to Private]

Just to wrap everything up: the reason that Windows selects Public, Private (or Domain) based on your current network settings is because it would cause mass mayhem for most end-users if they instead defaulted to Private (or Domain). None of their apps that required inbound network connections would work because the safe default for networks is Public, while the safe default for firewall rules is Private.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This needs to be reported to MS.

Comment: The fact that this prompt was here for sooooo long so many years up to 2023 at the time I am writing this comment, and it has never been fixed in a way that it would be more understandable to most people. That's how MS cares about its users..

Comment: It just doesn't make sense, in the settings it's written "Public (recommended)" for the Network profile type *but* when a firewall prompt opens "Public" is said "(not recommended)" but it's default checked ?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but you are right. The default is idiotic. Point one is that allowing any Inbound-initiated traffic is a risk. Point two is that you might enable it on a Private or Domain network where you have a reasonable trust of other devices. Point three is that you would almost never trust it on a Public network.
There are quite a few apps that request Inbound inbound exceptions when they don't need it. I can only conclude that the developers or packagers of the app did not really know what they were doing. They must think that, if they can bring up the prompt, you can decide what to allow.

Answer (score 1):

I am copying an answer from [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/public-versus-private-network-mystery/7964cfbf-cf49-45a7-9fab-86d9e6b9c28a) as it answered the question much clearer than I could explain.

> Private network or home networks are when you know and trust the
>   people and devices on the network. Computers on a home network can
>   belong to a HomeGroup. Network discovery is turned on for home
>   networks, which allows you to see other computers and devices on the
>   network and allows other network users to see your computer.
>
> Public network are for the networks in public places (such as coffee
>   shops or airports). This location is designed to keep your computer
>   from being visible to other computers around you and to help protect
>   your computer from any malicious software from the Internet. HomeGroup
>   is not available on public networks, and network discovery is turned
>   off. You should also choose this option if you're connected directly
>   to the Internet without using a router, or if you have a mobile
>   broadband connection.
>
> I would like to inform you that system network configuration does not
>   come configured with a network. You have to configure it when you
>   connect to the Internet connection for the first time. When
>   configuring the network connection to the system it might have got
>   selected to public network. However, you can change Public network to
>   Home network from sharing center.
>
> - Go to settings and click on Network & Internet.
> - Click on Wi-Fi on the left pane, and click on the Manage known    networks.
> - Click on the wireless network connected you want to manage and click    on Properties.
> - Now turn on Make this PC discoverable.

---

A point missing about the public network option is that sharing services SMB, etc.. should be disabled and open ports will be greatly limit. Less open ports result in fewer attack vectors. So, choosing public network when you are using an untrusted network is much wiser.

> Why is the default to allow public networks, and disallow private
>   networks?

This is likely because most non-technical users will select the default option, which is likely safer.

Comment: But it to the option that is "not recommended" because of "little or no security".  I am still confused.

Comment: My understanding, is they are advising users to not connect to public networks (café, airports, library, etc...) as they often offer "little or no security" which refers to Wi-Fi encryption and the potential for a MITM attack. Point is you **cannot** trust this foreign network, which may actively redirect traffic through a proxy they control to perform stripping of HTTPS. SSLStrip [ https://moxie.org/software/sslstrip/ ]

Comment: @safesploit Isn't there a way to allow the app to use your home WiFi to connect to the internet, but not let it connect to other devices in your home network nor use public (airport/coffeshop/...) WiFi?  That would seem the safest option, as both offered options seem to have disadvantages.  Or is that equivalent to checking neither of the two checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search shows a few forum posts where users have expressed similar concerns, provided below.

The synopsis from the [top source](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Logitech-Gaming-Software-6032-program.aspx) I could find  is that `lcore.exe`, the specific executable requesting this Windows firewall exception, allows you to customize your Logitech game controller behavior. In short, this allows for creating/modifying game profiles, launching games, and for exchanging game profiles with other users (import/export options), which explains why it is requesting external access.

Originally, I thought the reason the device(s) may need to communicate with an external network is to pull in updates. This could be the case, though having read further it seems that it is simply for communication relating to profile customization and sharing.

So, best practice would be to block it if you aren't using those features as it consumes additional system memory.

Sources:

- https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/487336-windows-firewall-with-logitech-gaming-software/
- http://www.shouldiblockit.com/lcore.exe-12534.aspx
- http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Logitech-Gaming-Software-6032-program.aspx